# Converting inches to feet inches in Java and outputting as return statment

Tags: java, if-statement, return

So im making a method that converts height to return as a String "5 feet 8 inches"
and teacher gave us this method so its going to be a return not display

This is what I have so far but Im sure what you can write in a return because it only takes one type

```
  public String convertHeightToFeetInches(int newHeight)
{
    int leftOver = newHeight % IN_PER_FOOT;
    if(newHeight < (IN_PER_FOOT * 2)){
        return "1 foot" + leftOver + "inches";

}
```

}

Im getting an return statment error everytime I run something similar to this.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an example of string concatenation.

Comment: I Upvoted Gteg's answer because it points out the flaw in your code... You have an `if` statement which returns a value when true, however you don't return anything when it's false. Since this method has a return type of `String` all logical paths must return a String of some kind, even empty.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is your code:

```
public String convertHeightToFeetInches()
{
  int leftOver = newHeight % IN_PER_FOOT;
  if(newHeight < (IN_PER_FOOT * 2)){
    System.out.println("1 foot" + leftOver + "inches");
  }
}
```

To return the string, simply do this:

```
public String convertHeightToFeetInches()
{
  int leftOver = newHeight % IN_PER_FOOT;
  if(newHeight < (IN_PER_FOOT * 2))
  {
    return "1 foot" + leftOver + "inches";
  }
}
```

Note however, that this doesn't put any spaces between '1 foot' and 'X inches'.  You'd get this:

> 1 foot3inches

You'll need to add some spaces.  Of course, for extra credit, maybe you want it to say simply "1 foot" rather than "1 foot 0 inches" when the remainder is zero.  In which case, you'll want to build up your string in a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), and then return the result once you're finished.  You're existing code, using a `StringBuilder` becomes (but still without the required space characters):

```
public String convertHeightToFeetInches()
{
  StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
  int leftOver = newHeight % IN_PER_FOOT;

  if(newHeight < (IN_PER_FOOT * 2))
  {
    buff.append("1 foot");
    buff.append(leftOver);
    buff.append(inches);
  }

  return buff.toString();
}
```

I'll leave you there at this point ... see how you go ...

---

EDIT:

> Im getting frustrated because every method I do is getting return statment error

In your code at present, you have two possible execution paths, but only one path returns a value.

```
public String convertHeightToFeetInches()
{
  int leftOver = newHeight % IN_PER_FOOT;
  if(newHeight < (IN_PER_FOOT * 2))
  {
    return "1 foot" + leftOver + "inches";    // we return a value - good
  }
  else                                        // there is also this execution path ...
  {
                                              // ... and you don't return anything - bad
  }
}
```

Comment: Im getting frustrated because every method I do is getting return statment error

Comment: @user1388557: I've edited my answer at the bottom to respond to your comment.

Comment: Greg hit it on the head - all control paths must return a String.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `String` return type to `int` return type and don't forget to return value in the end of the method.

```
public int convert heightToFeetInches() {
    int leftOver = (heightInInches % 12);
    return leftOver;
}
```

Or if you want to return as `String` do as like this one:

```
public String convert heightToFeetInches() {
    int leftOver = (heightInInches % 12);

    return String.valueOf(leftOver);
}
```

OOT: Are you C/C++/C# Programmer before? If yes, please make sure all your method and variable to make lower-case for the first word `heightToFeetInches()` don't use `HeightToFeetInches()` to prevent misunderstanding to other programmers. Because in Java we use upper-case to said that it is `class` or `interface` and lower-case for the first word to said it is `method` or `variable`.

Comment: Given that we haven't learned the second one I will not do that for this assignment but could you demostrate more of the problem. Because I want to return  feetVariable + "foot" + leftOver + "Inches".. How can I do all that in a return statment ? Or would I make more local variables

Comment: Do your process in local variable inside the method `heightToFeetInches()` and return the local variable as a `String` if you want like that one (Use the second method like I show you before). To make it clearly, please update your question and show what is your prefer output for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Think of how you would author the string without returning - just a normal print statement.  Then, instead of printing it, return that String.

You can print the returned result from it later; e.g. `System.out.println(convertFeetToHeightInches("68 inches"));`

Comment: Yeah but if I define a string in the method type I cannot return anything but a String??..Or could I convert my int's to a string via local variable before I send it through return?

Comment: What you do *inside* the method is all but immaterial, so long as your results are *captured inside of a String*, that you return.  You'd need to keep them as integers until you're ready to report your results anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a String Object and assign it a null value. Later, you can store your result inside this object and return *that*, like so:

```
public String convertHeightToFeetInches(int newHeight) {    

    final int IN_PER_FOOT = 12;
    int leftOver = newHeight % IN_PER_FOOT;
    String result = "";
    if(newHeight < (IN_PER_FOOT * 2)){
        result = "1 foot " + leftOver + " inches";

    } else {


        } return result;

}
```

You would call the method like this:

```
String conversion = convertHeightToFeetInches(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

//in your instanc variables

```
public static final int IN_PER_FOOT = 12;
private int height;
```

//your method

```
public String convertheightToFeetInches() 
{
    int leftOver = (height %= IN_PER_FOOT);
    int newHeight = (height % IN_PER_FOOT);
    return newHeight + "Foot" + leftOver + "Inches";
}
```

//my height method is not shown but its simple and you should already get that part